# Android not including native library

Tags: android, cmake, building

Trying to include a few dependencies which apparently are not being packaged with the APK; not certain if needing to do a CMake build or some configuration is missing to include the library; seeing the following error in logs:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.things.jar", zip file "/data/app/test-piauOz_7FY6SycVXNeMRVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test-piauOz_7FY6SycVXNeMRVA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libjavaupm_st7735.so"
```

Have the following dependencies:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
implementation 'io.mraa.at:mraa:1.9.0'
implementation 'io.mraa.at.upm:upm_zfm20:1.3.0'
implementation 'io.mraa.at.upm:upm_st7735:1.6.0'
```

More information found on the dependencies here: http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/upm/java/building.html

Comment: Seeing that the three dependencies are being included in the APK using the analyzer ( https://snipboard.io/0e98Ef.jpg ) but apparently there are two dex files; with the second one having also part of the dependencies ( https://snipboard.io/RF0seM.jpg ); not certain if that affects the loading of the library

Answer (score 0):

If the `.so` files aren't compiled for the arch you are building for then they will `not` be added to apk, this will lead to a runtime error when calling  `System.loadLibrary`.

Comment: How do I know or find out if it was built for the specified arch? The link I provided mentions running some cmake command; but I'm not certain if that is something I would somehow put into the CMakeList or have to run else-where. I'm not familiar with how to use or build with cmake

Comment: Here is a example on ubuntu to determine the architecture using ```file``` 
: 


```$ file libtensorflowlite.so```
and the output in my case is :
```libtensorflowlite.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped```